# Nestable not working for two lists

Tags: javascript

Hi there I have this code you can see the fiddle

```
[The fiddle][1]
```

The first list works just fine but the second is the same and I cannot drag its like its disabled or something and the height of columns in front of each other should be just like the first list, I dont understand why it does not work since its the same code.. can I make somehow when  I click a button to activate the second list or something..?

https://jsfiddle.net/yllbb/vhqhc8w4/23/

Comment: You are reusing CSS ids in your HTML code, you should only use them once. Not sure if that's the cause of your problem, but it is a problem.

Comment: @F0XS Yea sorry I eddited now it works fiddle